# Expand SimpleNamespace to handle AttributeError

Tags: python

**Objective**: Return `None` for attributes that does not exist in `SimpleNamespace`.

I created a `SimpleNamespace` class that converts my params from Python dictionary, so I can access configuration parameters via the dot notation (just like `argparse`). Here is my `SimpleNamespace` class I called it `Configs`, which converts `config_dict`:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Configs(SimpleNamespace):
    def __init__(self, dictionary, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__setattr__(key, Configs(value))
            else:
                self.__setattr__(key, value)

config_dict = {
    "learning_rate": 0.05,
    "epochs":10000,
    "loglevel":2,
}

opt = Configs(config_dict)
print(opt.epochs) # 10000
```

But for `argparse`, we can have default values. Taken from this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```py
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
```

How to expand my `Configs` class, such that any params not specified in `config_dict` will return `None` instead of `AttributeError`? For example:

```py
print(config.layers) # AttributeError: 'Configs' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

Can `config.layers` return `None` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silly way I just thought of is you could modify the `__getattribute__` method. For example:

```
class Configs(SimpleNamespace):

    def __init__(self, dictionary, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__setattr__(key, Configs(value))
            else:
                self.__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, value):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(value)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```